# change class names on equal interval of time (on hover)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show some animation effect on a div element when a user is hovering it. Can someone provide me code-snippet for this?

```
<div id="myDiv" class="c1"></div>
```

js.code

```
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){
    //after each 400ms
    //when mouse over #myDiv class should increment from c1 > c2 > c3 > c4 >c5
    //acutally its from cn > cn+1
}, function(){
    //after each 400ms
    //when mouse out #myDiv class should decrement from c5 > c4 > c3> c2 > c1
    //actuall its from cn > cn-1
});
```

Comment: What are the styles you have in classes c1,c2,etc.. It might be possible that you can animate that without classes.

Comment: I have to change background-position like from 0px to 200px to 400px ...

Comment: Is that position values a series, with the same value getting added up in each subsequent iteration? Like `200px` getting added up every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){
    //after each 400ms
    //when mouse over #myDiv class should increment from c1 > c2 > c3 > c4 >c5
    //acutally its from cn > cn+1
    $(function() {
        var $target = $('#myDiv');
          var classes = ['c1','c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'];
          var current = 0;

          setInterval(function() {
              if (current==4){
                clearInterval();
              }
              else{
                $target.removeClass(classes[current]);
                current = (current+1)%classes.length;
                $target.addClass(classes[current]);
                }
              }, 400); // 1500 ms loop

    });

}, function(){
    $(function() {
        var $target = $('#myDiv');
          var classes = ['c5', 'c4', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1'];
          var current = 0;

          setInterval(function() {
              if (current==4){
                clearInterval();
              }
              else{
                $target.removeClass(classes[current]);
                current = (current+1)%classes.length;
                $target.addClass(classes[current]);
                }
              }, 400); // 1500 ms loop
    });
});


});
</script>
```

**This is the jfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xDSaX/

You have only now to set the class what you want..

Comment: this.addClass ----> [object window] has no method addClass

Comment: I have changed my code, now I'm using a more simple function and works!